# A lower bound of an infimum on the sphere with $\varepsilon$-covering

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

Let

- $f$ be a linear function on $\mathbb{R}^n$,
- $\mathbb{S}^{n - 1} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \lVert x \rVert = 1 \}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}$,
- $\mathcal{C}_\varepsilon$ be an $\varepsilon$-covering of $\mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$, i.e., a finite subset of $\mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$, there exists $\bar{x} \in \mathcal{C}_\varepsilon$ such that $\lVert x - \bar{x} \rVert \leqslant \varepsilon$ with $\varepsilon > 0$.

Since $\mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$ is compact and $x \mapsto \lVert f(x) \rVert$ is continuous, there exists $x_\star \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$ such that $\lVert f(x_\star) \rVert = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}} \lVert f(x) \rVert$ and we can write $x_\star = \bar{x} + \delta$ with $\bar{x} \in \mathcal{C}_\varepsilon$ and $\lVert \delta \rVert \leqslant \varepsilon$. Thus, using the triangle inequality and the linearity of $f$, we have,
$$
\lVert f(x_\star) \rVert \leqslant \lVert f(\bar{x}) \rVert + \varepsilon \lVert f(\frac{\delta}{\lVert \delta \rVert}) \rVert.
$$
Since $\lVert f(\frac{\delta}{\lVert \delta \rVert}) \rVert \leqslant \lVert f(x_\star) \rVert$ by definition of $x_\star$, we get the following inequality for $0 < \varepsilon < 1$,
$$
\lVert f(x_\star) \rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{1 - \varepsilon} \lVert f(\bar{x}) \rVert.
$$

**Now, I am interested in a *similar but reverse* inequality on $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}} \lVert f(x) \rVert$.**

Similarly, there exists $x_\star \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}$ such that $\lVert f(x_\star) \rVert = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}} \lVert f(x) \rVert$ and we can write $x_\star = \bar{x} + \delta$ with $\bar{x} \in \mathcal{C}_\varepsilon$ and $\lVert \delta \rVert \leqslant \varepsilon$.

**How can I find an inequality like $\lVert f(x_\star) \rVert \geqslant h(\varepsilon) \lVert f(\bar{x}) \rVert$ with an explicit expression for $h(\varepsilon)$?**

If we try to apply the same reasoning as before, the [*reverse* triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) and the linearity of $f$ yield,
$$
\lVert f(x_\star) \rVert \geqslant \lVert f(\bar{x}) \rVert - \varepsilon \lVert f(\frac{\delta}{\lVert \delta \rVert}) \rVert.
$$
But $\lVert f(\frac{\delta}{\lVert \delta \rVert}) \rVert \geqslant \lVert f(x_\star) \rVert$ so this does not help here.

Comment: $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{S}^{n - 1}} \lVert f(x) \rVert$ may be $0$.

Comment: In fact, if the codomain of $f$ has dimension $< n$, the infinum will be 0. However, no matter how small $\varepsilon$ is, it is possible (indeed, likely) that none of the $\mathcal C_\varepsilon$ lie in the null space of $f$, so $\|f(\bar x)\| > 0$ in that case. Thus the best you can do in general is $h(\varepsilon) = 0$.